# Access object within an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

So i'm trying to access an attribute of a class object within an array.

```
document doc1 = new document(1,"Introduction to Java", "Ahmed Raya", "Summary of doc1","History of Java.docx");  
document doc2 = new document(2,"Object Oriented Programming", "Ahmed Raya", "Summary of doc2","Document2.pdf");
Object[] docary = {doc1, doc2};
```

I have an `open(directory)` function that takes the directory of an object (for example `doc1`'s directory is "History of Java.docx". What i'm trying to do is access the directory attribute of an object within the docary array.
This is basically what i want to do: `open(docary[k].directory);`where k is an integer variable inputted by the user. How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `reference` type of your declaring array to `document`. Also, consider renaming your `document` class to `Document` to better follow Java naming conventions. See the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) for more formatting info.

```
document[] docary = {doc1, doc2};
docary[0].directory(); //etc
```

Comment: Note that he could also cast `docary[k]` to the `document` type like this: `open((document) docary[k].directory)`if he need the array to be `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) You have to change the type of the array from Object to document.

```
document[] docary = {doc1, doc2};
```

---

Option 2) Cast the object to document.

```
open(((document)docary[k]).directory)
```

Comment: Another question, can I add and delete from an array of this nature? It seems like I cannot add or delete elements unless I use an ArrayList. If so, how can I do the same thing as above with an ArrayList?

Comment: Array's size is fixed. So you cannot modify its size nor remove or add elements. To use ArrayList instead, you can do the next: 
ArrayList<document> arrLst = new ArrayList<document>();
arrLst.add(doc1);
arrLst.add(doc2);

Comment: and to get an element: open(arrLst.get(k).directory);